# file writing in vs2010 (c++, win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, filestream

I asked this question earlier and you told me to mention the errors, 
so I will mention them now(I couldn't figure out how to continue the last thread I started,all I saw was an "add a comment" button and an "answer your question" button, so I had to correct the questio and ask it again, sorry about that):

My question is the following:
I'm using visual studio 2010 and I'm writing a win32 application(not a console application).
I need to know how to write to a file from this application.

I included these headers: windows.h, stdlib.h, string.h and tchar.h

I wrote a very simple hello world application and it ran just fine.

But when I tried to include iostream and fstream 
in my project the compiler gave me the following errors.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2039: 'abort' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2873: 'abort' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
IntelliSense: the global scope has no "abort"   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib  21  13  
IntelliSense: the global scope has no "exit"    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib  24  13
```

And when I include fstream.h,I get:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fstream.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\main.cpp  5   1   helloworld
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "fstream.h" c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\main.cpp    5   1   helloworld
```

Same thing for iostream.h

Why are these errors occurring?

Answer (score 5):

In C++, you should use `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`, `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>` (assuming you mean the C style strings. If you want C++ std::string, use `<string>` [without `.h`].

And you should use `<fstream>`, not `<fstream.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your :

`#include "stdafx.h"`

*is* the first include of you `.cpp` file.

Write other includes after this one :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
// ... and so on

int main(...) {

}
```

... this is a quite frequent mistake with Microsoft compilers (see [C++ cout gives undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858717/c-cout-gives-undeclared-identifier/16858948#16858948)).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wrote `#include "iostream"` instead of `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps .. Try to Check your errors reasons from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34%28v=vs.80%29.aspx